# Java Cast Object to Derived Class From Provided Instance

Tags: java

How do I cast an object to its derived class? Why does the below have a problem with casting as `(object.getClass())`?

```
public Object convertObjectToItsOwnClass(Object object) {
     object = (object.getClass()) object;
     return object;
}
```

So the above code should pass an instance of `Foo` back rather than passing an instance of `Object` back when `Foo foo` is sent to it.

Comment: What is the goal? Are you trying to return the name of the class as a String? That is doable.

Comment: @ThreaT Maybe you should clarify what you're intending to do with the casted object, the second you store the actual object in a reference, it will be cast to the reference type again. `Object obj = (String)inputObject;` will cast inputObject to a String and right back again to an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible** to use a dynamic Classname in a cast statement! And besides that it would not make much sense. At runtime Java knows of what type your object is, so there is no sens in casting it to that class.

If you want your code to react differently to different subclasses then you can use the `instance of` construct:

```
if (object instanceof MyClass) {
  MyClass myObject = (MyClass) object;
  //... 
}
```

If you only want to know which class the object is from, you can get its classname like this:

```
String className = object.getClass().getName();
```

**EDIT:**

It is not necessary to cast to the subclass. As mentioned before Java already knows about the subclass. See:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a = new A();
        Object b = new B();
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName()); //prints A
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getName()); //prints B
    }

}
```

Comment: So basically I want the equivalent of `if (object instance of MyClass)` like in your example, for every single `MyClass` in my project without having to write a million `if` statements

Comment: @ThreaT but for what goal? You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to achieve something like that, but its more or less like matching the className.

Comment: I thought it might be a job for reflection. Any ideas how?

Comment: If you tell me what you want, I might be able to advise on how to do that. You have to give us a bigger picture!

Comment: @ThreaT I have updates my answer with a short example. I think the problem is that the cast you want to do, is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

`object.getClass()` will give you `Object` type. But `out` is of type `String` so you will get `Type mismatch` compile type error.

After looking your comment `If I pass the method Person person then it should use the toString method @Override in Person class.` This can be done as below:

```
public String objectToStringConverter(Object object) {
     String out = object.toString();
     return out;
}
```

This will call `toString` method of your Person class.

Comment: @ThreaT Then just call `toString`, no cast necessary. The runtime will know that the object is a `Person` and call the correct override.

Comment: What do you mean by `cast an object to its actual class` the class is already in its own type. and if you want to cast to `String` class then use `String out = (String)object.toString();` simple.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `toString()` is of type `String`, so there is no need to cast in the example you provided. However, to answer your question, if you want to cast from one type to another and you know when writing your code (i.e. at compile-time) what the type is to which you wish to cast the object, then put the type in parens:

```
   Object untypedObject = // ...
   String typedObject = (String) untypedObject;
```

The code above does the cast from type Object to type String (throwing a ClassCastException as a result). There is also another method of casting (albeit less commonly used) when you don't know what the intended type is when writing your program (i.e. you don't know the indented type until runtime). Example:

```
   Class<?> runtimeClass = // ...
   Object untypedObject = // ...
   Object typedObject = runtimeClass.cast(untypedObject);
```

With the code above, you still have an Object on the left-hand side; however, the use "runtimeClass.cast()" ensures that the object is actually of the given runtime type (throwing an exception if it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

`String className = object.getClass().getName();`

This will give you the name of the class.

```
object.toString();
```

This will give you the toString representation of the object. Provided it's implemented by the object that is passed in the method. Remember if toString() method is not implemented by the object you passed in it will print the hashcode of the object. Which is default functionality of java.

Ok as per the latest comments from ThreaT if you want to cast it to the actual object type at runtime here is what you will have to do. I can provide you with a code sample later on weekend. 

**But here is the approach.**

Once the class name is found than create a class dynamically and load it. Dynamically created class will have a method that will check for instance of at runtime and return you the Casted object. But having said that I am not sure what will be the practical use.
If you can wait until weekend I can send you a sample. Or give it a shot yourself :). I hope it helps.

Comment: @ThreaT after you have cast it to its own type what would you do with it? I think that may answer how to answer this question